# Adding labels in prometheus_pushgateway

Tags: prometheus

```
    registry = CollectorRegistry()
    g = Gauge('some_metrices', 'metrics', "[node]",registry=registry)
    g.lables("worker").set(101)
    push_to_gateway('localhost:9091', job='batchA', registry=registry)
```

//If i try using without the lable [node] then i am able to create a metrices in my prometheus but if I use with labels i am getting an error.please tell me where i am going wrong

```
raise ValueError('Invalid label metric name: ' + l)
ValueError: Invalid label metric name: [
```

Comment: Were you able to figure out the correct syntax? I started similar to you but I'm not getting the syntax correct somehow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`[node]` is not a valid label name, you can't have square brackets in metric names. `node` would work.

I'd also suggest reading https://prometheus.io/docs/practices/pushing/

Comment: ya i am able  to add now i made some mistakes .Thanks @brian